# Discord bot deployed on Heroku but not gone live

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've deployed a Discord bot written in Node.js via Heroku. Deploying it works fine, no errors while deploying through Git and the CLI, but looking at the console this comes up:

```
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350186+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350187+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:2:16)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350189+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350191+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350192+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350194+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
2018-12-27T00:40:49.350195+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
2018-12-27T00:44:22.103872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=discordinsultbot.herokuapp.com request_id=d07b0456-29a2-4ecc-8574-f38108702f95 fwd="92.233.169.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-12-27T00:44:24.247588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=discordinsultbot.herokuapp.com request_id=eb51c01e-3959-4320-baae-bed3f257a878 fwd="92.233.169.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-12-27T00:44:31.125016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=discordinsultbot.herokuapp.com request_id=055c8a2f-ece4-4290-85fa-8e451c0bf3d0 fwd="92.233.169.246" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can't find much information on why it's happening. Currently on latest Git branch, has the Node.js buildpack enabled and the worker setup in the
Pocfile

Comment: More info probably will help. Is your package.json all correct, are you using right node version, some of what your code looks like etc.

Comment: Typically an issue like this is related to some sort of missing dependency that the app requires that is not in your `package.json` file or something similar.